# Play Framework 2.0.4 Java : impossible to convert ArrayList of POJOs in JsonNode

Tags: java, json, playframework, playframework-2.0, jackson

I have the following class :

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "update_field")
public class UpdateField extends Model {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.TABLE)
    public int                                 id;
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "update_proposition")
    @JsonIgnore
    public UpdateProposition                   updateProposition;
    @Column(name = "nom_champ")
    public String                              nomChamp;
    @Column(name = "nom_clair")
    public String                              nomEnClair;
    @Column(name = "old_value")
    public String                              oldValue;
    @Column(name = "new_value")
    public String                              newValue;
    public static Finder<Integer, UpdateField> find = new Finder<Integer, UpdateField>(Integer.class, UpdateField.class);
}
```

I get an ArrayList compound by instances of this class and try to convert it in JsonNode but it doesn't work, it blocks my server and I have to restart it.

```
public static Result getFields(final String requestUUID) {
        List<UpdateProposition> propositionList = UpdateProposition.find.where()
                                                                        .eq("update_request",
                                                                            UUID.fromString(requestUUID)).findList();
        List<UpdateField> result = new ArrayList<UpdateField>();
        for(UpdateProposition updateProposition : propositionList) {
            List<UpdateField> fieldList = UpdateField.find.where().eq("update_proposition", updateProposition.id)
                                                          .findList();
            for(UpdateField updateField : fieldList) {
                result.add(updateField);
            }
        }
        ObjectMapper om = new ObjectMapper();
        JsonNode node = om.valueToTree(result);
        // JsonNode node = Json.toJson(result);
        return ok(node);
    }
```

I tried by using directly `play.lib.Json.toJson(Object)` or with `org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper.valueToTree(Object)`, it's the same. I haven't any exception, the server is just blocked on the conversion method (as seen in debug mode). The ArrayList sems to be well-formed.

Someone has an idea ?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a mistake : I didn't import the right @JsonIgnore (I had to use the `org.codehaus.jackson.annotate.JsonIgnore` but, doing things quickly whith auto-completion in Eclipse, I imported the new version not available in my application)...